# IntelilJ 8.1 with 2 GWT modules

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add the [gwt-debugpanel](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-debug-panel/) into my project. I'm using IntelliJ 8.1, and I've setup a stripped-down, bare-bones project for testing. The source tree looks like this:

```
gwt-multi-module
  src
    com.gindin
      dummy
        DummyApp.gwt.xml
        client
          DummyApp.java
        public
          DummyApp.css
          DummyApp.html
      debug
        DebugPanel.gwt.xml
        client
          GindinDebugPanel.java
```

Notes:

1. All of the classes and files under the 'dummy' package were AutoGenerated by IntelliJ's "New -> GWT Module" wizard.
2. The classes & files under the 'debug' package were basically just copied over from the gwt-debugpanel's example project.
3. I've added the necessary script & reference to the nocache.js in the DummyApp.html

Now, when I go to run the project in IntelliJ, the hosted shell gives me an error message:

> [TRACE] The development shell servlet received a request for 'com.gindin.debug.DebugPanel.nocache.js' in module 'com.gindin.dummy.DummyApp.gwt.xml'
>   [WARN] Resource not found: com.gindin.debug.DebugPanel.nocache.js; (could a file be missing from the public path or a  tag misconfigured in module com.gindin.dummy.DummyApp.gwt.xml ?)

When I look at IntelliJ's module settings, the GWT facet shows both modules and their "Output Relative Paths".

How do I get IntelliJ to do whatever it needs to do? Is there something I'm missing where I point IntelliJ at the 2nd module's entry point?

thanks,

jay

Comment: What version of GWT are you trying out?

Comment: 1.6.4, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the configuration/setup steps as described on the gwt-debugpanel page aren't quite right, or at least not for my setup.

1. Don't include: `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.gindin.debug.DebugPanel.nocache.js"></script>` link in the HTML/jsp file
2. In the com.gindin.dummy.DummyApp.gwt.xml file, include `<inherits name='com.gindin.debug.DebugPanel'/>`

That's it. It now works (looks horid, but hey...it's on the screen, now I can make it dance).